# Was Wittgenstein a cognitivist?

Tags: wittgenstein

It is a common misconception to think that Wittgenstein was anti-theoretical in his Philosophical Investigations. There's simply too much evidence that doesn't support that conclusion.

At first I thought Ramsey reduced the whole conception of a correspondence theory of truth combined with deflationary tendencies, with some serious pragmaticist undertones, and for all I know that seemed like the right conclusion.

But, the genius that Wittgenstein was took a much more macroscopic view on how language works, and here are my thoughts...

The beetle in the box, the incomprehensible speech of a talking lion, family resemblemces, language games, the rule-following paradox, and the private language argument all point to something entirely unseen at the time, Something that linguistic cognitivists like Chomsky talk about to this day. In that, there is an embedded syntax and grammar that we all possess that allow us to mimic, gesture, point towards, name, command, and question our own deeply held beliefs.

Is this even considered as something that modern scholars think about, because I'd love to read a paper on this, and all of it feels right in my mind?

Comment: Maybe useful : Jonathan Ellis & Daniel Guevara (editors), [Wittgenstein and the Philosophy of Mind (Oxford UP, 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=jlVpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR3).

Comment: Your nuanced take on Wittgenstein's therapy is shared by prominent Wittgensteinian scholars. See [Wittgenstein’s ‘Non-Cognitivism’ – Explained and Vindicated by Fisher](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-007-9172-y) and [Hacker's book Wittgenstein's Place in Twentieth-Century Analytic Philosophy](http://pdfhumanidades.com/sites/default/files/apuntes/Hacker%2C%20P.M.S.%20-%20Wittgenstein%E2%80%99s%20place%20in%20twentieth-century%20analytic%20philosophy-Blackwell%20%281996%29.pdf).